# How to jump to a random function in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

i am making a python script that talks back to just for fun and i want it to pick a random subject to talk about each time here is a snippet of my code

```
def randsub():
     rand = random.randrange(1,3)
     rand.toString()
     randsub = "sub" + rand
     randsub()
```

but it keeps giveing me this error 
***TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the functions in a list, then use the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one at random for you. Functions are just objects, just like any other value in Python:

```
import random

def sub_hello():
    print('Well, hello there!')

def sub_nice_weather():
    print("Nice weather, isn't it?")

def sub_sports():
    print('What about them Broncos, eh?')

chat_functions = [sub_hello, sub_nice_weather, sub_sports]
randsub = random.choice(chat_functions)
randsub()
```

You got your specific error because you tried to concatenate an integer with a string (`"sub"` is a string, `rand` an integer); you'd normally convert the integer to a string first, or use a string template that supports converting other objects to strings for you (like `str.format()` or `str % (values,)`). But the string doesn't turn into a function, even if the string *value* was the same as a function name you happen to have defined.